# How get current usage of physical and virtual memory in java from code?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I need to get the percent of physical and virtual memory currently in use on my computer using java code.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you wanna accomplish with that but, take a look at  [MemoryMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) and [MemoryPoolMXBeans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html)

You can do things like:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean osMBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();

RuntimeMXBean runtimeMBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();

System.out.println("Total physical memory:" + osMBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize() / 1024 + "kB");
System.out.println("Free physical memory:" + osMBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize() / 1024 + "kB" );
System.out.println("Comm. virtual memory:" + osMBean.getProcessCpuTime() / 1024 + "kB" );
System.out.println("Total swap space:" + osMBean.getTotalSwapSpaceSize() / 1024 +" kB" );
System.out.println("Free swap space:" + osMBean.getFreeSwapSpaceSize() / 1024 +" kB" );
System.out.println("Operating system:" + osMBean.getName());
System.out.println("Arch:" + osMBean.getArch());
System.out.println("Processors:" + osMBean.getAvailableProcessors());
System.out.println("Process CPU time:" + osMBean.getProcessCpuTime() );
```

Comment: thank you so much! swap space is virtual memory, right? 
I'm just doing my homework for university :)

Comment: yes, Swap is the "memory" stored in disk, as know as virtual memory. You can easily find better definition googling for it ;)